# Is there anyway to cast mixed types while loading in BQ?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

I have a field in BQ table that defined as string, let's call that field 'foo'.
I am running a job that loads data from JSON to my BQ table.
The problem is, my 'foo' field in the JSON can be either number or string(as form "N/A").

I thought while loading JSON file, BQ was smart enough to cast number values for that fields into string. For example, `"foo": 48` would cast into `"foo": "48"`. But seems like it doesn't do it by default. Is there any way to configure `LoadJobConfig`(part of BQ python SDK) to accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't do it by default, but if you want to cast `foo` field value from a string to a number when possible and not fail the conversion on invalid values.
you could use

```
SAFE_CAST(foo AS INT64)
```

see example below

```
SELECT 
  foo,
  SAFE_CAST(foo AS INT64) AS converted_foo
FROM 
  UNNEST(["60", "234", "N/A"]) AS foo
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, this solution works after the values available in BQ. I am having problem when uploading them to the BQ from google storage.